# design thoughts on a physical simulation

Tags: oop, design-patterns, interface, simulation, physics

I'm basically new to OOP and besides a few programming basics in C++ have no experience whatsoever. For a college project I'm working on a physical simulation of the magnetic interactions of multiple protons.

My goal is to learn as many concepts and aspects to programming and apply those to my system. So what Ive been doing so far is reading into different design patterns and generally on how to approach such a project. Which only expanded my list of questions :D

I'm currently working of my class diagram. Basically my idea was to create a `physObject` class that implements different `behaviour`-interfaces. So in my case, all the `Protons` will implement `MagneticBehaviour`. I wanna try to create my design as loosely coupled as possible because I wanna provide reusability and flexibility. Later on it should be possible adding i. e. `GravitationalBehaviour` to simulate the gravitational behaviour of physical objects.

[Model class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYiIY.jpg)

This is my scetch of a class diagram. As I said I've tried to encapsulate the different variables needed into objects and applied the strategy pattern to make the calculations flexible based on the context of the simulation.

What I dont get is how to connect the classes. I.e. for the caclulation of the `ActingBField`, however that will be implemented, you'll need information of the distances to other `physObjects`. Also each time i.e. the location of a `physObject` changes, the `ActingBField` has to be calculated on every `phsyObject` that exists.

So it seems like I'll need to have a system, that automatically passes information within objects, if the value of an object changes. Which will kind of be a recursive pattern. So my first approach was to make `physObject` an `Observable` and every `Behaviour`-interface will be an `Observer` observing the variables needed. Then I've read into event-/ case-/ state-driven programming (not sure about the difference), which seems like a nice approach. I have no idea though how I would even visualize that kind of system in an uml diagram tbh.

Last but not least, all I've been doing so far is focus on the physical model of the simulation. However I figured I'll need to find a way to connect this model with some kind of user, that i.e. sets the time period of the simulation or selects which data to look at. How would that connection look like?

I'm really happy for any help, even a concept to look at would help tremendously since I'm really struggling to find any information.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Good question, but not the best forum. Stack Overflow is for when you're trying to write specific code and it doesn't work, or there's something very specific you haven't figured out how to do. This is a much more general question.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick response. I know this isn't exactly a coding question. I figured this has to be a common problem in programming though. Are there any other sources for code structure desgin thoughts?

Comment: I'm sure there is. Maybe on one of the science or tech sites. https://stackexchange.com/sites#science, https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology. If you ask it you could post a link to the question here in the comments. I'd be interested to see what the answers look like,

Comment: I'll make sure to keep you updated. Read the table of contents from your literature recommondation too. Seems like theres alot to find about design thoughts. I'll read into that ^^

Comment: @ScottHannen Here’s the link to the post: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/442542/physical-simulation-design-thoughts/443377#443377